# Error : Property 'modalStack' does not exist on type 'NgxSmartModalService'. Did you mean '_modalStack'?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I was trying to do ng build --prod in angular6, along with it I am using NgxSmartModal package for Modals. Don't know why the build is failing! Can anybody help me as I am in the middle of a production build failure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was trying to do the same, figured it out.
NgxSmartModalService got updated to version `7.2.0`

and in this update they have changed property `modalStack` to method

`getModalStack()` which does the same thing apparently. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Another solution to this could be in package.json you'd find "ngx-smart-modal": "^7.1.0". Just make it "7.1.0" and remove "^", it should work fine.